# Nextcord editing message with embeds

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, nextcord

I am trying to make a help command which edits the message from one embed to another when you react on it. But somehow, it isn't working. There's no error message.

My code:

```
@bot.command()
async def help2(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=helpembed1)
    await msg.add_reaction('➡')

    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) == '➡'

    try:
        reaction = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        return

    if str(reaction.emoji) == '➡':
        await nextcord.Message.edit(self=msg, embed=helpembed2)
```

I did some debugging and I think the error is in `await nextcord.Message.edit(self=msg, embed=helpembed2)`, but I literally have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: what about `msg.edit`? Why are you refering the class instead of the instance? Doesn't make sense since you already used `msg.add_reaction` not `nextcord.Message.add_reaction`... Also -- `discord.py` has resumed development, so using forks is no longer necessary.

Comment: Didn't work, but is it easier to do that in discord.py?

Comment: what do you mean by "didn't work"

Comment: Basically didn't do anything

Comment: what's the exact code you've used?

Comment: The question code, but changed to what you told me

 `if str(reaction.emoji) == '➡':     await msg.edit(embed=helpembed2)`

Comment: May I know what is the message you want to edit in `await nextcord.Message.edit(self=msg, embed=helpembed2)` ?

Comment: The message I want to edit is the message with the embed in it, wich is sent on command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nextcord.Message` is a class, to edit a message, you should use *a specific instance of the class*.

For example:

```py
msg = await ctx.send(embed=helpembed1)
...
await msg.edit(embed=helpembed2)  # <-- This uses the Message instance 'msg'
```

Nextcord (and dpy) have a built-in class `HelpCommand` which handles everything for you though, so you don't need to make one by hand. [This gist](https://gist.github.com/InterStella0/b78488fb28cadf279dfd3164b9f0cf96) is a good walkthrough on how to use it.